# Daily image rotator based on a column value

Tags: image-display

We have a sharepoint2013 web application with one site collection, one top level "http://spta" and some subsites(e.g http://spta/aboutus)
in the top level there is a Publishing image library with "Keyword" column.

- Image1.jpg  Keyword:aboutus,contactus,....
- Image2.jpg  keyword:conferences,aboutus,...
- ...

Now I want to show all images with "aboutus" keyword in "aboutus" subsite. and I know how to do that, but I want to display only one image each day.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any out of the box solution. You need to create a Custom WebPart to do this.

1. Create a Visual Webpart - Add an Image Control
2. Get current URL
3. Now read images from Picture Library into an array

**Logic to rotate**

We need to store current image information as well as the date that image was set. We can use web property bag for this.

On first page load, set the image control to the first image. Then store the image ID and current date time into web property bag

For subsequent page load, read date time value from property bag. Now compare with current time. If more than 24 hours difference, then read image with next ID, set image to control and store current date time into web property bag.

Comment: how about using <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/> to filter data view ,but I need to have day number

Comment: You can try that, but I believe in that case you need to populate current date values in the image properties?